# seq uses both comma and dot as a decimal separator

Tags: bash, seq

Coming from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23885058/5642859) answer I'm trying to output a sequence of numbers using a dot as a decimal separator.

This works:

```
$ LANG=en_US seq 0.1 0.1 0.8
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8

$ LANG=en_US seq 0.1 0.1 1.0
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
0.9
1.0
```

But this doesn't:

```
$ LANG=en_US seq 0.1 0.1 0.9
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
0,9
```

Why? How can I fix it?

Comment: It is giving me correct result !! Which version of seq are you using ?

Comment: `seq` is not part of bash -- it's an external tool your OS vendor may or may not supply, and because it's not POSIX-standardized, there are no guarantees about which behavior it should or shouldn't implement. Maybe this should be tagged `unix`?

Comment: (Also, because it's provided by your OS vendor, you really need to specify that OS in the question to give folks a reasonable chance at being able to reproduce the behavior at hand).

Comment: BTW, what behavior do you get setting `LC_ALL=C` rather than `LANG=en_US`? If that fixes things, you'll want to look into non-`LANG` locale variables.

Comment: @batMan I'm not sure how to figure out the version of seq. `seq --help` does not yield this information, but `man seq` says `GNU coreutils 8.25` on the bottom left.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `LC_ALL=C` fixes this. Thanks!

Comment: use `seq --version`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent *any* locale settings (such as `LC_NUMERIC`, a likely culprit here) from influencing behavior:

```
LC_ALL=C seq 0.1 0.1 0.9
```

That said, I don't advise using `seq` at all. It's a nonstandard command, not guaranteed to be available on all UNIX platforms or to have any specific behavior when it *is* available. An a floating-point-capable alternative, consider `awk`:

```
LC_ALL=C awk -v min=0.1 -v max=0.9 -v inc=0.1 \
  'BEGIN { cur=min; while (cur <= max) { print cur; cur += inc; }; exit; }'
```

Comment: Yeah locale settings are definitely playing some role. Good pick. ++

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because of the `LANG` variable that sets locale setting and causing `seq` to behave like this. It's not clear *why* but to fix it **EXPLICITLY** you can us `tr`. For eg.

```
$ LANG=en_US seq 0.1 0.1 0.9 | tr "," "."
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
0.9
```

Comment: BTW, re: reasoning behind my edit -- see [When should code formatting be used for non-code text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text) on meta; to quote the consensus answer, "code formatting shouldn't be used for emphasis on regular words".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : I'll make a note of this Charles. Thanks for this link.